# Middle click doesn't open a new tab, but only in the address bar

Tags: windows-10, browser, mouse

I have a Logitech MX Anywhere 3 mouse, which I recently started using with a new laptop. Whenever I try to open a new tab by searching it in the address bar and middle-clicking it, it just opens in the current tab. It works fine when I middle-click any other link from a website or my bookmarks.

No idea what the issue is, it worked fine on my last laptop, it happens with Chrome and Edge as well.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Since you have this problem on Chrome & Edge, I would assume it is a problem with your OS/settings, &c.

Comment: Windows 10, same as the previous laptop

Comment: Does the mouse have something like LogiTech Options to install and set?  Check that. I have that software on one laptop for one mouse.

Comment: It does but the middle button is mapped as the middle button

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, the mouse software(LogiTech Options) had a specific app configuration on chrome and a few other apps, deleting it fixed the issue.